# How to import JSON data into a Google spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-custom-function

Google Sheets has an [IMPORTXML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342) function to import data from various structured data types including XML, HTML, CSV, TSV, and RSS and ATOM XML feeds.

Is there a similar way to import JSON formatted data?

Comment: you can also you =importdata("url to json")

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Currently there is no any Add-on which offer this functionality, so you have to create or import custom functions by *Script Editor* available in *Tools* menu (for Spreadsheet). Then re-paste the content of `ImportJSON.gs` from [bradjasper's GitHub page](https://github.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON) and save it.

After that, you can use `ImportJSON` function, for example:

```
=ImportJSON("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_popular?v=2&alt=json", "/feed/entry/title,/feed/entry/content", "noInherit,noTruncate,rawHeaders")
```

Here is another example:

```
=split(concatenate(ImportJSON("https://api.binance.com/api/v1/klines?symbol=BTCUSDT&interval=1m&limit=1")), ",")
```

Read more:

- [The ImportJSON library](https://blog.fastfedora.com/projects/import-json) at Fast Fedora
- [Import JSON data into Google Spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2658980/55075) at Stackoverflow
- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) at Google Developers

Comment: is there a way to do this in new google sheets? how do i get this running?

Comment: is there a way to paste the json object in the argument, instead the url?

Comment: I've tested these steps today (as of 2018) and they still work in the latest Sheets (_Tools->Script editor_) and import the functions.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to paste a JSON object you can use http://www.convertcsv.com/json-to-csv.htm to convert it to a CSV and then import that into Google Sheets.

If you want to rotate the data from columns to rows you can use http://www.convertcsv.com/transpose-csv.htm

I found this easier than messing with an addon script.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to fetch JSON from an API endpoint and then pluck out a particular value into a cell (via formula) in Google Sheets.

So I created this custom function in Apps script:

```
/**
 * Inspired by https://thisdavej.com/consuming-json-web-data-using-google-sheets/
 * @customfunction
 */
function SKLIMA(address) {
  const url = `https://api.zapper.fi/v1/protocols/klima/balances?addresses%5B%5D=${address}&network=polygon`;
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  const object = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  return object[address].products[0].assets[0].tokens[0].balance;
}
```

The `@customfunction` `CURRENTWEATHER` at https://thisdavej.com/consuming-json-web-data-using-google-sheets/ was helpful for me.